# Query on Shrinking Table - Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, blob

I'm trying to shrink a LOB whose owner is **TEST** and the tablespace it resides is on **USERS**.

EDIT: Currently, the **default** tablespace for **TEST** schema is tablespace called **TESTTBL**.

I have enabled row movement on the table.

If I try to shrink the particular LOB using:

```
ALTER TABLE test MODIFY LOB (image) (SHRINK SPACE);
```

...will it shrink and release space, becuase the schema **TEST** has default tablespace **TESTTBL** and data resides in **USERS**.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: I'm yet to. I need to know if that is the right way.

Comment: @BalazsPapp have edited the question.

Comment: Just create a test table with the same config and run the command.

Comment: I don't get why you think you can't. There are completely different things... You are comparing shrinking segments (already existing segments) vs the default tablespace where your segments will be written if you don't specify one.

Comment: After all I wanted to know how it works, that is all.. I did try and it did not shrink the LOB segment

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have a Basicfile LOB, because shrink is not supported with Securefile LOBs. The segment is not being moved, so the default tablespace and the tablespace of the segment is not relevant now. So a simple test is:

```
SQL> create table t1(c1 clob) lob (c1) store as basicfile;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 select lpad('X', 4000) from dual connect by level<=10000;

10000 rows created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select bytes/1024/1024 from user_segments where segment_name = 
     (select segment_name from user_lobs where table_name = 'T1' and column_name = 'C1');

BYTES/1024/1024
---------------
             80

SQL> alter table t1 enable row movement;

Table altered.

SQL> delete from t1 where rownum <= 5000;

5000 rows deleted.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> alter table t1 modify lob (c1) (shrink space);

Table altered.
```

And the LOB segment became half the size after the shrink operation:

```
SQL> select bytes/1024/1024 from user_segments where segment_name = 
     (select segment_name from user_lobs where table_name = 'T1' and column_name = 'C1');

BYTES/1024/1024
---------------
        39.8125
```